# {ROM} Change to the Actionbar ICS framework to modify placement of first menu item

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

**Screenshot of what I'm referring to:**

http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-searchview.png

**The source is here:**

https://github.com/TeamKang/frameworks_base/blob/4.0.3/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java

**Problem:**

I have a Galaxy Nexus and I wanted to change the ActionBarImpl.java file so the ActionBar's navigation icon (the one currently fixed to the left) will default to be fixed to the right. (I want to modify the framework because I want it to do this on all existing apps on that phone)

I hold my hand right-handed, and with the Galaxy Nexus's size, I have issues reaching the back button with my thumb. I feel that adding this option could help several people with the same issue.

My plan was to try to re-index the order of there arrangement when calling the .show(), but I am having difficulty understanding what a lot of it's doing since I'm not well versed with Android ROM building.

**Question:**

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, just to see if anyone knew where to point me for this or details to see if this is even possible.

**Edit:** Note - I am under the impression that this is possible since Android automatically arranges the menu unless you declare a custom model. (That's at least what I understood from the SDK documentation.)